# wsimport and Android or any other ProxyGenerator for android?

Tags: android, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I am currently developing an Android app i previously developed for IPhone. My Backend is built using WCF service with basichttpEndpoint, i also enabled RESTful methods for better support with other Mobile platforms as well.

Now i want to access my existing WCF service(SOAP/REST endpoint) on Android but i need some good ProxyGenerator to consume my services. I just google around for some solution and i found wsimport and wsdl2java(Axis) are two options in java domain. But i am still unable to find any solution related to Android. Can anyone suggest me the best practice in such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any custom libraries.  You can check out droid-fu.  It has some httpclient helpers to send http requests and read response bodies.  But I'm afraid you won't really find any beefy rest or soap client libraries for android.

Comment: I was really wondering if someone has worked with some proxy generator. As i have working background in .net, i really miss this luxury in android framework.